# postrgres where in json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am planning to do a function.
But don't even get to a Select Result.

I have a table "t_table1"

```
 id |              json_data              
----+---------------------------------
  1 | {"key": "key1", "value": "3222"}    
  2 | {"key": "key1", "value": "224"}     
  3 | {"key": "key1", "value": "1243"}
```

In the function I want to send a json via PostgREST Api und receive as result the lines of the table.
In the Post the json would look like:

```
{"ids":{[1,3]}}
```

the result would be:

```
 id |              json_data              
----+---------------------------------
  1 | {"key": "key1", "value": "3222"}     
  3 | {"key": "key1", "value": "1243"}
```

I want to do it first with a select:

This works (with hardcoded ids):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  api.query1(incoming_ids jsonb)
 RETURNS table  (id int4,json_data jsonb)
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
SELECT * from t_table where  id =ANY(ARRAY[1, 3])   
$function$
```

Select:

```
select api.query1('{"incoming_ids":[1,3]}')
```

But now I want of course this line "SELECT * from t_table where  vid =ANY(ARRAY[1, 3])"
Uses the incoming ids.

I have tried so much different thinks that would be too much
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to use ANY(), does it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  api.query1(incoming_ids jsonb)
 RETURNS table  (id int4,json_data jsonb)
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
select * from t_table where id in (
SELECT x::int from jsonb_array_elements(incoming_ids)  x)
$function$
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=51a0e0ef17c039047d1315d86cf8a282)

EDIT: In postgres 10 there is a slight modified version. Instead of direct cast as x::int, you use a double cast like x::text::int.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  api.query1(incoming_ids jsonb)
 RETURNS table  (id int4,json_data jsonb)
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
select * from t_table where id in (
SELECT x::text::int from jsonb_array_elements(incoming_ids)  x)
$function$
```

[DbFiddle demo for postgres 10](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2274ec705bffb63e658913ab65db63a)

Comment: Hi,
First: DBFiddle Cool Tool!! Thanks

Now I see the problem. I am running on Postgres 10. Then it doesen't work. It works as of Version PG11.
We will do a upgrade. But I think in autumm. Do you may have a solution for the PG10?

Comment: @Zio, in postgres 10 you need x::text::int instead, Edited and added dbfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` to parse the incoming array `ids` and compare it to the column `vid`, e.g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.query1(incoming_ids jsonb)
RETURNS table (id int4, json_data jsonb) LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
AS $$
 SELECT vid,json_data FROM t_table
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements($1::jsonb->'ids') j(ids)
 WHERE vid = ids::int4
$$
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=07c8ac3da2877e997808da2e2f5d0841)

Comment: Hi also for you: First: DBFiddle Cool Tool!! Thanks Now I see the problem. I am running on Postgres 10. Then it doesen't work. It works as of Version PG11. We will do a upgrade. But I think in autumm. Do you may have a solution for the PG10?

Comment: @Zio perhaps this will help you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c9aecc6a7592403b20183ad9624a6e0b